# MEAN application with Angular 2, serving node_modules folder for systemjs.config.js

Tags: angular, express

Is it a good practice to serve the "node_modules" folder as static to the front-end. I have an Angular 4 app which is using systemjs.config.js file to load the dependency modules, along with the core-js, reflect-metadata etc. to bootstrap the application and load the main component. 
I have this on the node server to serve all of the node_modules folder.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")));
```

I am somehow not so comfortable in serving the node_modules folder. It not only might affect the performance of the site but exposes all the folders which I might not need.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You shouldnt be using SystemJS for shipping a production application.  Use the Angular CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100% agree with the smell. You should not be sending the `node_modules` to the client.

Also you should follow @cgatian's advice and use the CLI, it will handle the bundling for you as well as injecting into the `index.html` the compiled bundles.

It also has a very nice way to include 3rd party scripts via the `.angular-cli.json`.

Comment: Thanks. Never heard of .angular-cli.json. Will look that up.